# servlet life cycle while loadOnStartup

Tags: java, servlets

When we mention any servlet as `loadOnStartup` in web.xml then its `init` method is called for sure. Just wanted to confirm does `service` and `destroy` methods are also get called or not?  If not when they get called?

Another question is as it is mentioned every where `init` method is called only once. Does that mean when the servlet gets the request first time, `init` method will be called and then `service` will be called.

But destroy will not be called. When the second request it will simply call the service method again but not init method. Is this understanding correct? But when container decides to call the destroy method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `loadOnStartup` means that the servlet will be loaded (and its `init(..)` method called during container startup. Otherwise, as you suspect, it will be loaded when the first request comes
- containers have only one instance of each servlet. When they create it, they call `init(..)`. When the context is undeployed (for example - the container is stopped), `destroy()` is called

Answer (score 2):

`loadOnStartup` gives priority on which threads loads before other threads. The Servlet container will load the servlet and call the `init` method. If `loadOnStartup` isn't mentioned in `web.xml`, the serlvet will be instantiated when there's a request call that requires the servlet.

Initialization of the servlet happens only once. Once it's initialized, the servlet container keeps it.

For request handling, the servlet container calls the serlvet's `service()` method and when the servlet container is shutdown it will call all the servlet's `destroy()` method and remove the servlet from the container.

For more info view some explanation [here](http://www.servletworld.com/servlet-tutorials/servlet-life-cycle.html), or from [Java EE](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafi.html).

Answer (score 0):

When we enable `load-on-start-up enable` in `web.xml` then our servlet program will be instantiated during server start up. Means every request will take same amount of time for their response.